# How to set GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to increase the `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`, after a research I saw that is possible do this using: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len`, but I didn't find any tutorial or article that allow me to do this in PDO, is possible specify this in the configuration or something like? Or should I write this in the server configuration? And if I can't access to the server configuration how can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't have looked very hard... Google is my Buddy :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly didn't find this, thanks, but I don't understand a thing: should I do something like this: `$query = "SET group_concat_max_len = 2048;
  SELECT * FROM country;` or I should execute two query? If so, this will save the max len?

Comment: A seperate query, probably just after you connect to the database

Comment: As long as you use the same PDO connection, you can set a session variable in one `query()` and it will remain in effect for a subsequent `query()` in the same session. There's no need to execute multiple statements in one query.